# How to Retrieve Data from Enum Based On Condition?

Tags: c#

I have One Enum in my Code

```
 public enum AdmitStatus
    {
        Admitted = 1,
        NotAdmitted = 2,
        Pending = 3
    }
```

I want to create one method having Boolean Parameter Status :

```
public JsonResult GetAdmitStatusSelctListValuesBasedOnStatus(bool Status);
```

So when Status Value will be true I only want Admitted in List and When Status is False I want NotAdmitted and Panding in List So how can I get this ? And I also want int of that Enum Values as I need to bind it with select list .

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Be sure to include sample input data, and expected data based on that input data.

Comment: Since it's *based on Status*, why don't you use an `AdmitStatus` argument instead of `bool` and `switch` on it, eventually? In your current code, when does `AdmitStatus` come into play?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if(Status)
    statuses= statuses.Where(status=>status==AdmitStatus.Admitted);
else
    statuses= statuses.Where(status=>status!=AdmitStatus.Admitted);
```

You can then retrieve the int equivalent of those Enum Values like this:

```
statuses= statuses.Select(x=>(int)x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont show what your list looks like but you can filter the list using LINQ like so

```cs
return from x in list
where Status ? x.AdmitStatus == AdmitStatus.Admitted : x.AdminStatus != AdmitStatus.Admitted
select x;
```

but I think a better alternative would be to use AdmitStatus as the GetAdmitStatusSelctListValuesBasedOnStatus method argument instead of the bool argument

```cs
public JsonResult GetAdmitStatusSelctListValuesBasedOnStatus(AdmitStatus[] statuses);
```

then you can change your query to

```cs
return from x in list
where statuses.Contains(x.AdmitStatus)
select x;
```

To generate a select list from an enum you can do something like this

```cs
return new SelectList(from x in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AdmitStatus)) select new { Value = (int)x, Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(AdmitStatus), x) } , "Value", "Name");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAdmitStatusSelctListValuesBasedOnStatus(bool Status) {

    if (Status) {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(AdmitStatus)).Cast<AdmitStatus>().Where(x => x == AdmitStatus.Admitted).Select(v => v.ToString()).ToList();
    } else {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(AdmitStatus)).Cast<AdmitStatus>().Where(x => x != AdmitStatus.Admitted).Select(v => v.ToString()).ToList();
    }
}
```